# Submitting a Remote Form via rails-ujs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, rails-ujs

I'm slowly modernizing a legacy Rails app, and am trying to swap out `jquery-ujs` for `rails-ujs`.

I've installed `rails-ujs` via the asset pipeline, and know that this is working as expected: in my browser's console, I've got access to the `Rails` object.

But, when I try to use the `Rails.fire` event to submit a form, I can't get the expected behavior.

In my view:

```
<%= form_with model: post, method: :PUT, url: post_update_url(post), local: false, html: { data: { target: "posts.form", action: "ajax:success->posts#submitSuccess" } } do |f| %>
  // Form stuff
<% end %>
```

In my Stimulus controller:

```
submit() {
  Rails.fire(this.formTarget, 'submit');
}

submitSuccess() {
  console.log("Success!")
}
```

If I remove `local: false`, then the form submits just as expected, and the page re-loads. But as soon as we add AJAX back, `Rails.fire()` simply returns `false`. How would I update this to programmatically submit this form remotely?

(Note that my Stimulus controllers are managed via Webpacker, while rails-ujs is installed via the asset pipeline. Due to constraints within my app, I would like to avoid `rails-ujs` via Webpacker right now, if possible.

Comment: have you added `//= require rails-ujs` to application.js ?

Comment: Why not just use Stimulus or plain JS to submit the form?
e.g. `this.formTarget.requestSubmit()`. AFAIK there's no special reason you need to be using Rails ujs for basic form UX; is there a reason you are?